# Como ejecutar acción de controlador

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Quisiera ejecutar la acción de un controlador desde un script ya tengo capturado las 2 variables a utilizar TIPO  y NRO_REQUERIMIENTO y estas 2 quiero quiero enviar a mi acción CargarRequerimiento_Datos que está lista para recibir los 2 datos.

Gracias.

1. Controlador

   ```
   [Authorize]
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult CargarRequerimiento_Datos (string tiDocu, string NuReqi)
   {
       // 1. Obtenemos repo_Requerimiento y el modelo RequerimientoModelo
       Repositorio.Almacen.repo_Requerimiento Buscar_Datos = new Repositorio.Almacen.repo_Requerimiento();
       RequerimientoModelo m = new RequerimientoModelo();

       // 2. Asignamos valores a utilizar para la búsqueda del documento
       m.CodEmpr = VariableGlobal.scodEmpresa;
       m.TipoDocu = tiDocu;
       m.NuReq = NuReqi;

       // 3. Ejecutamos método que busca y obtiene resultado
       Buscar_Datos.CargadRQ(m);

       // 4. Asignamos datos obenidos en la vista de Datos y Detalles
       return View("Requerimiento", m);
   }
   ```
2. Script

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quieres ejecutar ese controlador de forma asíncrona?

Comment: Así es ya he realizado el script y ejecuta la acción pero no me refresca la vista requerimiento a pesar que tiene el return View.

Comment: Coloca código en ves de imágenes. Gracias :D

Comment: Puedes colocar el html que devuelve esa vista? para ayudarte a buscar la mejor forma de manejarlo. La usas para llenar una tabla, un dropdown?

Comment: Agregué el "document.write(response);" y me devolvió la vista. Gracias colocaré el resultado final.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**ACTUALIZADO!!!**

Con el siguiente script logré ejecuta mi controlador y devolver la vista con la información obtenida.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Mostrar_Requerimiento(TIPO, NRO_REQUERIMIENTO)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("CargarRequerimiento_Datos", "Requerimiento")',
            method: "POST",
            data: { 'tiDocu': TIPO, 'NuReqi': NRO_REQUERIMIENTO },
            success: function (response) {
                $('#divPage').html(response);
            },
            async: true
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Si estás utilizando Jquery, quedaría mejor con $('#MyDIV').html(response); en lugar del document.write.

Comment: Quedo mucho mejor, Gracias.

Comment: Una consulta adicional, al devolver mi Vista hay un script que está ejecutando conflicto y no el diseño de mi tab. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filtertype' of undefined
    at c.<computed>._initfilterpanel (eval at <anonymous> (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2), <anonymous>:8:91706)

Comment: Verifica los nombres de las variables/propiedades que estás utilizando y que "filtertype" no sea "undefined".